# Dashboard QGIS displaying specific information from attribute table

Tags: qgis, visualisation, dashboard

I'm using QGIS 3.22. Biatowieza.
For a better visualization, I would like to create a little dashboard, where I only display 2-3 colums from the attribut table.
Similar to the "identify Objects" arrow, but only with specific information AND a different design.
I have installed the plugin QGIS Dashbourd (https://github.com/luisCartoGeo/QGIS_Dashboard/archive/refs/heads/master.zip), but this is not what a quite need for this task (the design is very nice though).
Can u give me a hint where I need to look to get the job done?

[image: In the added image you can see that instead of the display of the "identify object arrow", I would prefer, if a visible box shows the information I need in the design I want.]

Comment: Did you have a look at the new annotation tools, available since QGIS 3.22? https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog322/index.html#annotations

Comment: I worked through the this Dashboard-Youtube solution. It covers some of my problems: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJTV90SvRAM